Using Eclipse Transformer to upgrade Richfaces to Jakarta 10 didn't work
I'm trying to deploy our richfaces heavy applications to EAP 8. Replacing it will be the next goal, but for now i just need it to work as before.
Has anybody succesfully tried that already?
After combining the richfaces jars with the maven-shade-plugin and using the Eclipse Transformer on that jar i tried opening a page which contains an a4j Output Panel and i get this error:
Caused by: jakarta.faces.FacesException: Expression error: Named object org.richfaces.OutputPanel not found.
at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.util.Util.notNullNamedObject(Util.java:480)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.InstanceFactory.createComponentApplyAnnotations(InstanceFactory.java:695)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.InstanceFactory.createComponent(InstanceFactory.java:289)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:438)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//jakarta.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createComponent(ApplicationWrapper.java:570)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//jakarta.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createComponent(ApplicationWrapper.java:570)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.faces.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.createComponent(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:507)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.faces.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:151)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//jakarta.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:139)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//jakarta.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:57)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//jakarta.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:163)
    at deployment.svweberv-frontend-2439.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.faces.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:177)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//jakarta.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:139)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//jakarta.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:57)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:63)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:166)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:358)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:329)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:69)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//jakarta.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:57)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//jakarta.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:163)
    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.4.redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.faces.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyNextHandler(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:139)
    at deployment.svweberv-frontend-2439.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)

I can't find a org.richfaces.OutputPanel class in any of the 'old' richfaces jars.
jar is WEB-INF/lib of my WAR; and no metadata-complete="true" in my faces-config.xml.
I don't know what to do with this error... Any ideas?
